# C++ Placement New with Templates

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

**Background**

I'm working on an embedded C++ project in which I'm building a simple state machine using inheritance. The idea is that each state will inherit from a base class called State, and the state manager will create and destroy sub-class instances during state transitions. In order to avoid using the heap, I'd like to use *placement new* with a statically allocated array.

**Question**

How would one use C++ templates to determine the size of the largest State sub-class at compile time, in order to create an appropriately-sized static array? I know this is possible because [TouchGFX (an embedded C++ GUI library)](http://touchgfx.com/documentation/html/page_application_development.html#sect_application_development_malloc) uses the exact same technique to manage its Presenter and View sub-class instances.

Comment: Maybe something something and a `union` with all the possible instantiations and some waving of hands and then `sizeof` the `union`?

Comment: Are you sure avoiding the heap here is actually a win?

Comment: If you can use boost, you may want to consider boost::variant<>. But then if you can use boost you will find that they've already written a template state machine for you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/index.html

Comment: @MagnusHoff - this might work, but I gathered from TouchGFX's docs that their magical template solution was automatic.

Comment: @BillyONeal - this is an embedded project so RAM is pretty scarce. I want to avoid the possibility of an overflow if at all possible.

Comment: @Neil: Forcing all your objects to allocate the maximum possible size isn't a good thing to do when RAM is scarce.

Comment: @Neil: Their documentation seems to explicitly require a `TypeList` with all the types that may be contained, which points at the union-based solution.

Comment: @BillyONeal - true, but there will only be one state instance in memory at a time, and I need to ensure there's enough space for the heaviest one at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regarding what is done in touchGfx

I think the

```
typedef meta::TypeList< MainView,
                        meta::TypeList< LeftView,
                        meta::TypeList< RightView,
                        meta::TypeList< DownView,
                        meta::TypeList< UpView,
                        meta::Nil > > > >
                      > ViewTypes;
```

part is for some purpose i don't globally understand, however with this trick it can know the max size of it place

## In code

the code (simplifyied for exactly what you want):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
template<typename ...All>
struct maxSize;

template<typename Member>
struct maxSize<Member>{
  static const size_t member_size = sizeof(Member);
  static const size_t size = member_size;
};

template <typename Member, typename... Rest>
struct maxSize<Member, Rest...> : maxSize<Rest...>{
  static const size_t member_size = sizeof(Member);
  static const size_t size = (member_size > maxSize<Rest...>::size ? (member_size) : (maxSize<Rest...>::size));
};

template<typename... sizeMax>
void* allocSpace() {
  return new char [maxSize<sizeMax...>::size];
}

int main(){
  allocSpace<char, char[10], int, double>();
  std::cout << maxSize<char, char[10], int, double>::size << " " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;
}
```

## Edit

That was my code, or what i can do to arrange what you want, but the type list is surely somthing like this:

```
struct NIL{
  static const size_t size =0;
};

template<typename Member, typename Tail>
struct typeList{
  static const size_t size = Tail::size > sizeof (Member) ? Tail::size : sizeof(Member);
};
```

Comment: `sizeof()` does not always work with `std::vector<T>`